# TDD / Unit testing a windows application?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm very new to doing any type of testing, but I've done a little reading and it seems like its a great way to go. I love the idea of being able to just click a button and ensure that the codebase is stable. The freedom to hack away as long as the tests pass is very intriguing.

However, my software is a windows based program. Basically what it does is interact with other windows on the users desktop, and move them around the screen based on certain criteria. If XX image is visible, move that window to x/y coords. If F9 keyboard shortcut is pressed on that window, move it to x2/y2 coords. Etc.

I'm at a loss as to how I would go about any sort of testing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you're a beginner, I'll add a reminder here, that you need to be careful of *what* you test. You wish to test your logic, not windows. In order to do this, you need to separate your concerns into a class (or classes) that contain your logic, and classes that contain wrappers (proxies) to APIs that you use - you don't test the APIs. They work until you prove otherwise.

You will want to test your classes, and stub or mock the proxies. In the above example, if for example, you're using the Windows API commands to deliver your solution, you'll put the commands that move the window into a WindowsProxy class, and mock the calls, **verifying** that the calls to them are made, but not actually running them in the test.

If you are using .NET, and Windows-Forms, or some similar framework, you'll want to use a pattern that supports testing, such as [MVP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx). You'l want to write your tests to exercise the **Presenter**, while stubbing or mocking the **View** (your window) and the **Model** (any API or domain object you use).

Here's a sample architecture:

```
public interface IView { ... }

public class View : IView
{
   private Presenter _p;
   View()
   {
      _p = new Presenter(this);
      ...
   }

}

public class Presenter
{
   presenter IView _v;
   Presenter(IView view)
   {
      _v = view;
   }
}
```

Using a mocking framework like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), you can easily stub and mock the view, and test the presenter (where all your logic will reside). With Moq, you can have the class under test set values on the mock, and later verify their values (e.g. the coordinates of the window).

Hope this helps. I spend a lot of my time developing Win-Form based custom controls, and develop them with TDD. It is not impossible or even difficult, once you get the hang of it.

Let me know if you need any further elaboration.

Assaf.

Comment: Thanks. I think your explanation is a bit over my head though. I'm coding in a scripting language, so there aren't many frameworks available. But I wanted to start learning about this whole unit testing process, and applying it to my current project. As you note, the logic code and the windows code is all mixed together, so I probably have a lot of refactoring to do. I guess its hard to get good feedback without giving more details of my app. Other examples include, checking pixel color at a certain x/y and moving window. If no pixel color in X minutes, move window. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended to UnitTest windows so you'd better to refactor your app to Model-View-Controller(any kind of this pattern) and test the Controller and Model classes standalone.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do unit testing of this type of application, you need to distinguish between testing what you see on the screen, and testing the state of the application.

If I take one of your examples:

> If F9 keyboard shortcut is pressed on
>   that window, move it to x2/y2

You could structure your code so that you can easily trigger the function/method to move the window. Then you would want to interrogate the window state and determine where it is. If the window state reports that it is at position x2/y2, that's a positive result.

There is a lot of value in these types of tests. Of course there's always a chance that where the window thinks it is, and where it actually appears might not match. So you should still do some testing where you are clicking buttons and looking at the screen. You just don't need to do all your testing like that.

Comment: For example, the actual moving always succeeds. I haven't ever found a case where the move has failed. It simply calls the Win32 API MoveWindow function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Usually the problems arise that the window state is falsely detected, and then the MoveWindow function never gets called. So yeah, I'll need to test the what I see on the screen and compare with the state of the app. This will require some substantial refactoring since this code is very much just thrown together.